# How to fix npm peer dependency issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` that has the following modules that are conflicting:

1. `react-router` which needs `react 0.13.x`
2. `redbox-react` which needs `react@>=0.13.2 || ^0.14.0-rc1`

I just did an `npm install react` and it installed `react@0.14`

I am trying to install `react-bootstrap` which needs `react@>=0.14.0`.

I have been a few solutions:

1. delete `node_modules` from all the `node_modules` of dependencies every time I update
2. delete and reinstall all modules every time you face an issue
3. upgrade to npm 3.x which is still pre-release and

What is a good way of fixing these issues without having to do 1 or 2 which is npm version agnostic.

P.S.: All the modules referred to here have been installed locally.

Comment: So if `react-router` needs `react-0.13` - install `v0.13`. Otherwise it's not clear what your actual problem is: you either satisfy the version requirements, or you don't have packages working/installing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the latest version of `react-router` (currently `1.0.0-rc3`).

The `react` module is [only listed as a dev dependency](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/package.json#L58), and the requested version is `0.14.0` so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Thanks @nick, this fixes the problem for `react-router`. What can I do specifically for `react-bootstrap` and `redbox-react`  and broadly speaking,in general to avoid the issue?

Comment: Hm, does react 0.14.0 not satisfy the requirements for those other modules?

Comment: I reinstalled `react-bootstrap` and `redbox-react` after uninstalling the existing versions which were complaining about the peer dependencies and it works. Thanks Nick, I will accept the answer and close this question.